# Check all parent nodes when child node is selected in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

How can I check all parent nodes when a child node is checked in jstree?

```
$('#select_cats').jstree({
            "core" : {
                "themes" : {
                    "responsive": false
                }            
            },
            "types" : {
                "default" : {
                    "icon" : "fa fa-folder icon-state-warning icon-lg"
                },
                "file" : {
                    "icon" : "fa fa-file icon-state-warning icon-lg"
                }
            },
            "checkbox": {
                "three_state": false
            },
            "plugins": ["types", "checkbox"]
        });
```

Comment: Are you using the checkbox plugin? Also, could you give us the HTML of `#select_cats` or perhaps a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is the solution to this problem.

When you check a node, all of that nodes parents will automatically been checked

```
$('#categories').on('activate_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
      if (data.instance.is_leaf(data.node)) {
        var parentnode = data.node.parent
        do {
          data.instance.check_node(parentnode)
          parentnode = data.instance.get_node(parentnode).parent
        } while (parentnode)
      }
    })
```

Comment: when parent node is selected  by user all its child node should get selected. When any child node is selected all its parent node sh get selected. it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `"three_state"` property to `true` you will get all parents up to the root checked, like here - [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/umjefvjd/)

If you want multiple items be selected at once so that the parent will turn to fully selected state, add `"multiple" : true`to tree `core` config

Comment: When "three_state" property is set to true then on select parent node its all child node get checked as well. which I don't want.
Secondly I want parent node fully selected if any of its child is checked.

Comment: So you want parent nodes get fully selected if any of children is checked. What if the parent is checked? None of child nodes should get selected, just the parent stays selected?

Comment: when parent node is selected by user all its child node should get selected. When any child node is selected all its parent node sh get selected. it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var selected = instance.get_selected(), i, j;
for(i = 0, j = selected.length; i < j; i++) {
  selected = selected.concat(instance.get_node(selected[i]).parents);
}
selected = $.vakata.array_unique(selected);
selected.pop('#');
```

All of selected nodes with parents is in `selected` variable.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/6rICTokWciU

Answer (score 0):

With **JsTree 3.3.6** I got it in the following way:

```
// bind to events triggered on the tree
$('#ID_OF_TREE').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
  var selected = [];
  for (i = 0; i < data.selected.length; i++) {
    selected = selected.concat($('#ID_OF_TREE').jstree(true).get_path(data.selected[i], false, true));
    //first false=I want an array; second true=I want only IDs
  }
  selected = selected.unique();
  console.log(selected);
});

Array.prototype.unique = function () {
  return Array.from(new Set(this));
}
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44376705/3473765) answer to remove duplicates and following the [documentation](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_path(obj%20[,%20glue,%20ids])).

Every time you select any checkbox, it will get all the parents of all checked checkboxes and push them into `selected` array. Finally it will remove duplicates coming from checked sibilings (which will cause multiple IDs of their parents in the array). 
`data.selected` is an array coming from the JsTree changed event.

Obviously you can bind this code anywhere you want, simply replacing `data.selected` with

```
var all_selected = $('#ID_OF_TREE').jstree(true).get_selected();
```